# How to resolve "ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key" in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcrecaptcha

I want to implement google recaptcha into my application but it is throwing the error. I do not know what I have done wrong.

I have installed nuget package of `GoogleRecaptcha` and then got the `site key` which is basically a public key and `private key`. I then included `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>` in `<head>` section and `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>` into form. In `web.config`, I have added the keys. I tried different keys but still not working.

> ERROR for site owner: Invalid site key

```
@using reCAPTCHA.MVC


<html>
<head>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.Recaptcha()
            @Html.ValidationMessage("ReCaptcha")
            <input type="submit" value="Register" />
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeYD1wUAAAAAIzGhgDrIoI_OD7PUzwTJIQdpqGs"></div>
        }

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you added your website(domain i.e. http:www.xyz.com) on google captcha dashboard ?

Comment: @AnmolRathod, Just now i added that but how to do this for local host. this is giving me error `Localhost is not in the list of supported domains for this site key.`

Comment: @User9895
I have same problem! did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have added `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` to domains and it worked for me now.